# Why don't the stars in rateit appear unless I refresh the page?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am using JQuery rateit plugin to implement star ratings in my meteor application. I'm using rateit inside a form which is supposed to leave a review and the rating points.

```
{{#if reviewedProvider}}
    <hr>
    <strong>Review Details</strong>
    {{#with providerReviewDetails}}
        <p>{{this.reviewMessage}}</p>
        <span class="rateit" data-rateit-value="{{this.pointsRated}}" data-rateit-readonly="true"></span>
    {{/with}}
{{else}}
    <hr>
    <form id="reviewProvider">
        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="writeReview">Write a review</label>
            <textarea name="reviewMessage" id="writeReview" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea><br>
            <label>Rate provider</label><br>
            <span class="rateit"></span>
        </div>
        <button class="margin-top-5 btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{{/if}}
```

And after submitting the form, the form should be replaced with the review message and the stars rated.

```
'submit #reviewProvider': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var providerId = this.assignedProvider;
    var buyerId = this.userId;
    var jobId = this._id;
    var timeReviewed = new Date();
    var ratedPoints = Template.instance().ratingPoints.get();
    var reviewMessage = "";
    $('textarea[name="reviewMessage"]').each(function() {
        reviewMessage += $(this).val();
    })
    Meteor.call('reviewProvider', providerId, buyerId, jobId, timeReviewed, ratedPoints, reviewMessage, function(error) {
        if(error) {
            toastr.error('Failed to submit review. Please try again.');
        }
   })
}
```

After submitting the form, I could see the form being replaced with the review content. I could see the review message but cannot see the stars rated unless I refresh the page.

Comment: Are you using any package for rateit? If I were to guess, the rateit initialize function is working only on page render. That would explain why the page refresh triggers the stars to be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your rate it in a template

```
<template name="rate">
    <span class="rateit" data-rateit-value="{{this.pointsRated}}" data-rateit-readonly="true"></span>
</template>
```

Then initialize the plugin when ^ template renders

```
Template.rate.onRendered(function() {
    $('.rateit').rateit();
});
```